# Show that $\int_E |f|^q \leq CN^{q/p} |E|^{1-q/p}$.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $0<q<p<\infty$. Let $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be measurable with finite measure. Let $f$ be a measurable function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that the set $N = \sup_{\lambda >0} \lambda^p| \{x\in \mathbb{R}^n: |f(x)|>\lambda\}| <\infty$.

1- Prove that $\int_E |f|^q$ is finite.

2- Refine the argument of (1) to prove that $\int_E |f|^q \leq CN^{q/p} |E|^{1-q/p}$,

where $C$ is a constant that depends only on $n, p$ and $q$.

I want to ensure my argument for (1) is correct, and I could not verify the second one. Any help is appreciated. Here is my proof for point (1).

**My proof**

Define $E_\lambda = \{ x \in E: |f(x)| > \lambda\}$. Using Layer-Cake representation:

$$
\int_E |f|^q = q \int_0^\infty \lambda^{q-1} |E_\lambda| d\lambda = q\left( \int_0^1 \lambda^{q-1} |E_\lambda| d\lambda  + \int_1^\infty \lambda^{q-1} |E_\lambda| d\lambda \right).
$$

The first integral is finite,

$$  \int_0^1 \lambda^{q-1} |E_\lambda| d\lambda<\infty.$$

The second integral is estimated as follows:

$$\int_1^\infty \lambda^{q-1} |E_\lambda| d\lambda \leq \int_1^\infty \lambda^{q-(1+p)} \lambda^{p} |E_\lambda| d\lambda \leq \int_1^\infty \lambda^{q-(1+p)}\lambda^{p} |\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n: |f(x)| > \lambda \}| d\lambda $$

$$\int_1^\infty \lambda^{q-1} |E_\lambda| d\lambda\leq N \int_1^\infty \lambda^{q-(1+p)} d\lambda < \infty.$$

Then

$$\int_E |f|^q < \infty.$$

Comment: Looks good. You could remark that the first one is finite because $|E|<\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of splitting the integral at $t=1$, let us split it at some arbitrary $t>0$:
$$
\int_E |f|^q = q\left( \int_0^t(..) d\lambda + \int_t^\infty (..) d \lambda \right)
$$
Then using your calculations (but explicitly computing the finite integrals) gives
$$ 
\int_E |f|^q \le q \left( \frac{ t^q }q|E| + N \frac{t^{q-p}}{p-q}\right)
$$
Now, we minimize the right-hand side with respect to $t$. (It is a convex function in $t$.)
Its derivative is zero at
$$
t = \left( \frac N{|E|} \right)^{1/p},
$$
which results in
$$
\int_E |f|^q \le \left( 1 + \frac q{p-q}\right) N^{q/p} |E|^{1-q/p}.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much for this idea. It never came to my mind. I have one more question: The constant $C$ should depend on the dimensions $n$, but it does not here!

Comment: There is nothing in the formulas depending on $n$? Everything is estimated in terms of measures of sets in $\mathbb R^n$, so there is no place, where an $n$ should appear. Maybe I missed something?

Comment: I do not think you missed something. But the statement of the question is confusing.